# how to display the username in all my web pages...?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to display the username on all my web pages after successful login, here i can able to capture the username on home page for this i used ejs but if the client want to move to other page from home page the username is not visible , here i missed some logic how to handle this username on all the pages

Thanks in advance...........

```
app.post('/Home', function(request,res){     
    console.log(request.body);
     const check = "select count(*) as cnt from users_info where Name ='"+request.body.userid +"' && Password = '"+request.body.password +"' ";
    mysqlConnection.query(check,function(err,result){
        console.log(result);
        var Records= result[0].cnt;
        console.log(Records);
        if (Records== 1)
        {
            response.render('Login', {username:request.body.userid});
        }
        else
           console.log('User name or Password is invalid');
            //  res.render('Login.ejs', {error: 'User name or Password is invalid'});
    });  
    }); 

app.post("/Login/search", (request,response) =>{
    console.log(request.body.search) 
    const check = "select * from users_info where Name NOT LIKE '${request.body.search}%' ";



 mysqlConnection.query(check,function(err,result){
        const arr = result ;
        console.log(app)
        console.log(arr.length)
        let countRecords = arr.length;
        if (countRecords>0){
            const names = arr.map(({ Name }) => Name).join('\n');
            console.log(names.length)
            console.log(names)

            res.render('Login-success', {users:names});

            // res.send(names);
        } else {
            console.log('Request failed...')
        }


    });  
});
```

header.ejs

```
<body>
         welcome  <%=  username%>
```

how to use this header file on Home.ejs, search.ejs etc pages.....

Answer (score 0):

You may create file called "header.ejs".

```
welcome <%= username%>
```

For the rest of web-pages you can include the header.ejs file by using include command.

```
<% include header.ejs %>
```

Note: I consider that, header.ejs and all other files are located in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for response ,here what i am getting the error is username is not defined after move to /Login/search from /Home page , i mean is it mandatory for mentioning the username :res.body.userid at the time of rendering a file in app.post(/Home ){------}  and if it is mandatory then how to mention this username :res.body.userid  at the time of rendering a file res.render('Login-success', {users:names}); in app.post(/Login/search){-----}///here how can i implement

Comment: You may set the cookie value once you get the username after the login. Once you are done with setcookie, under the header.ejs page you can write like <div onlLoad="getUSername()"><span id="username"></span></div>
Using the jquery and javascript, get the value of the username and set into span tag. Once you done this for the header.ejs file, you are able to have username on everypage.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the auth object with your render method

```
res.render('Login-success', { auth: req.session.auth });
```

and then

```
welcome <%= auth.name %>
```